# How to skip a nested level in mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document structure

```
{
    name: 'bob',
    data: [
        {
            sport: 'football',
            data: [
                {
                    event: 'a',
                    date: '1628163910'
                },
                {
                    event: 'b',
                    date: '1628146503'
                },
                // ...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If the user doesn't filter the sport, then I want my query to ignore the sport property and search all the sport arrays to filter by the date. Here's what I thought it would be, but this doesn't work?

```
Oddsmatcher.find(
    { `data.$[].date`: { $lte: DATE_MAX_FILTER } }
)
```

Comment: You have to specify field name `data.football.date`, can't skip fields.

Answer (score 0):

You cant skip fields, instead you should rethink your data modelling. 2 collections one for sports and one for events will do. You can then find all events irrespective of sports or with sport filter.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
With your updated model, you can query as below

```
Oddsmatcher.find(
{ `data.data.date`: { $lte: DATE_MAX_FILTER } }
)
```

---

As you can't skip a level, construct $or condition programmatically with a clause for each sport. This works if the sports is fixed or you have a master list of sports defined somewhere in system.

```
{
$or: [{
        'data.football.date': {
            $lte: DATE_MAX_FILTER
        }
    }, {
        'data.horse_racing.date': {
            $lte: DATE_MAX_FILTER
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

Or redesign you model such that sport is a field inside each event.

```
{
name: 'bob',
data: [{
        sport: 'football',
        event: 'a',
        date: '1628163910'
    }, {
        sport: 'football',
        event: 'b',
        date: '1628146503'
    },
    {
         sport: 'horse_racing'
        // horse_racing events
    }, {
        sport: 'tennis'
        // tennis events
    },
    // ...

   ]
}
```

Comment: I've edited the original question, would this model work now? or do I have to make the event objects an immediate ancestor of the data property?